# Do OAuth clients need to validate tokens as part of authorization code grant?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Does an app using authorization code (with or without PKCE) to obtain access + id tokens on behalf of a user need to also validate those tokens (signature, not expired, audience, etc.)?

If so, what for? Since the client is using TLS and pointing to the provider it's been configured with, what attacks/threats does that client also validating the token mitigate?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance you are right and the spec basically allows for not checking tokens directly returned from the token endpoint over TLS as you suggest indeed, but:

Firstly, one may argue that if a signature is present, it is there for a reason and it should be validated since the Provider is also free to return tokens without a signature (alg="none") if it did not want/need the Client to validate.

Secondly, there are known attacks ("IDP mixup") that trick the Client into talking to the wrong token endpoint as a way of stealing the Authorization Code: verifying that the ID token returned does not match the expected signature would at least stop the Client from processing an ID token produced by an attacker.

Thirdly, it would be good for the Client to protect itself against broken or compromised IDPs in general, avoiding replay attacks or similar.

I guess when you're doing all of it in a single domain, i.e. Client, AS and RS are all under control of the same organisation and the relationships between them are fixed and one-to-one only, technically verification would be overkill based on current knowledge and known attacks.

But in case your use case spans multiple security domain, in general it is better to verify than it is to assume.

Comment: In your examples there you specifically mention ID tokens, do those same arguments all hold true if the client isn't actually using ID tokens, but instead just getting access tokens and using them on behalf of the user to make API requests?

Comment: access tokens are not validated (and not meant to be) by the client